# How can I make unix sort work properly using the underscore as a field separator?

Tags: unix, sorting

When I sort `foo` and `foo1`, I expect `foo` to come first, which is what happens ordinarily with unix `sort`.

```
$ echo -e "foo1\nfoo" | sort
foo
foo1
```

But when I add and underscore and use the `-t` and `-k` options, it doesn't produce the same sort order.

```
$ echo -e "foo1_3\nfoo_3" | sort -t_ -k1
foo1_3
foo_3
```

What is the correct set of options to use to make `foo_3` come before `foo1_3`? I have `LC_COLLATE=C` and am on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
echo -e "foo1_3\nfoo_3" | sort -t_ -k1,1
```

[As the sort manual states](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html#index-_002dk-2):

```
`-k POS1[,POS2]' `--key=POS1[,POS2]'
    Specify a sort field that consists of the part of the line between
    POS1 and POS2 (or the end of the line, if POS2 is omitted),
    _inclusive_.
```

Comment: PS: I never knew this and was always puzzled by sort -k's behaviour, untill this question triggered me to find out what was going on. So thanks a lot for asking!